# How to make a work on a web-page without "freezing" it

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a google chrome extension that works in facebook.

I'm running a function each  10ns

```
 myVar = setTimeout(search, 10);
```

*search* function arranges my friends stories according to an input text element, it puts friend(whose name appears in the textbox) stories at the top.
It stops when a button is pressed.

search function :

```
function search()
{
   var name = "";
   var stories_parent = document.getElementsByClassName("tickerActivityStories")[0];
   var last_moved_element = stories_parent.firstChild;


   if(document.getElementById("srchTxt")!=null)
     name = document.getElementById("srchTxt").value;

   if(name != null && name!=" " && name !="")
   {
     isSearching = true;
     var stories = document.getElementsByClassName("tickerFeedMessage");

     for(i = currentStoryIndex+1 ; i < stories.length ; i++) 
      { // a loop in stories searching for my friend stories
         currentStoryIndex = i;

         if(stories[i] != null && stories[i].firstChild != null)
         {
         var personName = stories[i].firstChild.innerText;//getting my friend name
          if(personName == null)
            stories[i].firstChild.remove();

         if(personName!= null)
          {
         if(personName.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) == -1)
             continue; //cheking if name isn't my friend name so continue


           var element = stories[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
           stories_parent.insertBefore(element, last_moved_element);
            last_moved_element = element.nextSibling;
            //moving my friend story up
          }
         }
    }

     fireEvent(document.getElementsByClassName("pam uiBoxLightblue tickerMoreLink uiMorePagerPrimary")[0],"click"); //load more stories pressing"show more"
     myVar = setTimeout(search, 10);

  }
}
```

The problem is that when running the function I can't scroll down in facebook unless the button is clicked.

How can I run the function and surf facebook simultaneously?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what you `search` function is actually doing

Comment: @LcSalazar I mentioned it

Comment: Use web workers? remember that Javascript is single-threaded, it'll lock the browser up if the process it's doing takes too long.

Comment: I know that web worker would not work because I access elements , am I right ?

Comment: [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) may help you. Don't poll, use events.